# How does Swift disambiguate Type Arguments in Expression Contexts?

Tags: swift, generics, compiler-construction, grammar, ambiguous-grammar

Take a look at the following two expressions:

```
baz(Foo<Bar, Bar>(0))
baz(Foo < Bar, Bar > (0))
```

Without knowing what, `baz`, `Foo` and `Bar` are (`baz` can be a type or a method, `Foo` and `Bar` can be types or variables), there is no way of disambiguating whether the `<` represents a type argument list or a less-than operator.

```
// two different outcomes, difference shown with parentheses
baz((Foo<Bar,Bar>(0)))      // generics
baz((Foo < Bar), (Bar > 0)) // less-than
```

Any sane programming language should not rely on what `baz`, `Foo` and `Bar` are when parsing an expression like this. Yet, Swift manages to disambiguate the below expression no matter where I place whitespaces:

```
println(Dictionary<String, String>(0))
println(Dictionary < String, String > (0))
```

How does the compiler manage this? And, more importantly, is there any place in the Swift Language Spec. where the rules for this are described. Looking through the `Language Reference` part of the Swift book, I only found this section:

> In certain constructs, operators with a leading `<` or `>` may be split into two or more tokens. The remainder is treated the same way and may be split again. As a result, there is no need to use whitespace to disambiguate between the closing `>` characters in constructs like `Dictionary<String, Array<Int>>`. In this example, the closing `>` characters are not treated as a single token that may then be misinterpreted as a bit shift `>>` operator.

What does `certain constructs` refer to in this context? The actual grammar only contains one production rule that mentions type arguments:

> explicit-member-expression → postfix-expression­ `.` ­identifier­generic-argument-clause­<sub>opt</sub>

Any explanation or resource would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that the Swift compiler is Open Source. Here is a starting point with an overview of the architecture and links to the source code: https://swift.org/compiler-stdlib/#compiler-architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Martin R, I found the relevant part of the compiler source code, which contains a comment that explains how it resolves the ambiguity.

[`swift/ParseExpr.cpp`, line 1533](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-2.2-RELEASE/lib/Parse/ParseExpr.cpp#L1533):

```
///   The generic-args case is ambiguous with an expression involving '<'
///   and '>' operators. The operator expression is favored unless a generic
///   argument list can be successfully parsed, and the closing bracket is
///   followed by one of these tokens:
///     lparen_following rparen lsquare_following rsquare lbrace rbrace
///     period_following comma semicolon
```

Basically, the compiler attempts to parse a list of types and then checks the token after the closing angle bracket. If that token is

- a closing parenthesis, bracket or brace,
- an opening parenthesis, bracket or period without whitespace between itself and the closing angle bracket (`>(`, `>[`, but not `> (`, `> [`),
- an opening brace or
- a comma or semicolon

It parses the expression as a generic call, otherwise it parses it as one or more relational expressions.

As described in the book [Annotated C#](https://books.google.de/books?id=g6axWRRpJZwC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=type+arguments+in+expression+productions&source=bl&ots=Hz1nlhHw4L&sig=V6N5D5JMoRVWFVB2ZXlguIIMvPw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1v_zu_PLLAhUEECwKHd5FDxUQ6AEIYjAJ#v=onepage&q=type%20arguments%20in%20expression%20productions&f=false), the problem is solved in a similar way in C#.

Comment: Your answer helped me appreciate how good your question is. I guess I've seen so many poorly worded questions recently that I did not credit yours with due attention. +1 for both Q and A. Very nice find in the parser comments! The only thing I could add at this point is that it is also fun and instructive to play with the compiler directly from the command line: `swiftc -dump-parse hello.swift` (or `-dump-ast`, `-dump-type-refinement-contexts`, etc.).